# How to keep on adding/showing items on my page while scrolling the vertical bar

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Thanks a lot for all ur supports...Now I've a problem to resolve..I want to scroll the vertical bar and show the items in the page to appear as the scroll will go down(the way it happens in facebook page..It keeps on adding lists,items,comments,images as u keep on dragging the vertical scroll bar down)...Right now I don't have any code segment to use..and I've least idea regarding this..Please help me out..Preferable language/script could be asp.net,html,javascript,css,C# as I don't have any knowledge on PHP and MySQL..

Comment: My opinion: don't. It's annoying. I expect the scrollbar to indicate how much more there is to the page, not let it just keep on growing forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is called infinite or continuous scrolling, and it's mostly done in combination with jQuery.You can find some links below - though i couldn't find a working demo (and i know nothing about asp.net).

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/asp-net/b8381915-06d9-4538-b4bb-5ac2a8e73f34/implementing-continuous-scrolling-ui-pattern-in-aspnet.aspx

http://weedallaboutit.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/infinite-scrolling-with-an-asp-net-webform-jquery-and-a-little-bit-of-code/

http://studentguru.gr/b/xinarisc/archive/2011/05/29/infinite-scrolling-with-jquery-amp-asp-net.aspx

Comment: I followed your first link. I used the code given in that site.On my dispaly page, there is a grid populated with data from my table(database) but after scrolling down,"Loading.." is not appearing and as well grid is not populated with the next batch of data.Any idea,what is going wrong?

Comment: Lots of things could be wrong. I suggest you post a (well documented) new question for this issue...